Creating object without assigning it to variable
I often use initializing of objects without assigning it to variable. For me it is convenient, but at some point I understood that I can't find documentation why this is possible in C++ language (first I saw this approach in Java). Can you provide some documentation example for C++ with this approach? For some reason I can't find documentation with such examples.
Examples of what I am talking about:
//example1 (I initialize some data AS string object): 
if (std::string{params["name"]} != std::string{userDb["name"]} {
                res.code = 401;
                res.body = "{\"success\":false}";}

//example2 (I initialize object and call it's method):
RedisDao{}.get(key);


It's creating temporaries that go away after the expression is evaluated.

Good reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime

Constructing std::string objects from (presumably) non-null const char* values just for comparison is a bit of an anti-pattern. The function std::strcmp does this without incurring extra memory allocations, or there is std::string_view which is also non-allocating but provides a string interface that includes comparison operators.

Thank you all for your comments. Very useful!
